# Why is this ball half black when using principled bsdf but not if using other shaders?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

These are the node setups.

Using Principled BSDF:
[image: Principled BSDF]

Using Diffuse BSDF:
[image: Diffuse BSDF]

Comment: From my limited testing it seems t be caused bu the *Light Path* node, whatever it it. Seems like the *Principled BSDF* shader doesn't really like complex Light Path mixes. Might well be a bug

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to add a bit of hot pink layer to the cyan ball, without affecting it much. If the cyan ball is glass (say 0,875 transmission) the pink would make the cyan blue. I need cycles to show pink on the side the camera is facing. Not on its backface, not on the other side also. I use a duplicate of the ball, make it half pink with a gradient factor, scaled it up a tiny tiny bit so the colour show. But I don't think this is the correct nor efficient way. Any suggestions of a workaround without using two ehm... balls?

Comment: Use any shader other than Principled, it seems to work well

Comment: In *current release* build I have the same result, however using a later build (42a5624 on linux) does not reproduce. I would download a [buildbot build](https://builder.blender.org/download/) and you will probably see the same thing.